# How to change select box values based on the other drop down list values in rails query ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Here I have to model User and UserType. If I change the usertype then the user belongs to the particular usertype will be listed in the drop down. This is my code.

*.html

```
<div class="control-group string optional payslip_user_type_id">
    <label class="string optional control-label" for="payslip_user_type_id">Employee Type</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <%= f.collection_select :user_type_id, UserType.all, "id", "name", prompt: '--select--' %>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group string optional payslip_user_id">
    <label class="string optional control-label" for="payslip_user_id">Employee Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <%= f.collection_select :user_id, @users, "id", "name", prompt: '--select--' %>    
    </div>
</div>
```

the jquery file is

```
$("#payslip_user_type_id").change(function(){
    var url = '/payslips/new?user_type_id=' + $(this).val() + ''
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'script',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){ $("#payslip_user_id").html(data); }
  });
})
```

the controller code is

```
if params[:user_type_id].present?
      @users = UserType.find(params[:user_type_id]).users
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js 
      end
    end
```

and the new.js.erb file is

```
<% if @users.present? %>
    <%= select_tag 'payslip_user_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@users, "id", "name") %>
<% else %>
    <%= select_tag 'payslip_user_id', '' %>
<% end %>
```

when ajax request made, I could see select options in browser console. But it is not changed in the html. Please any one help me.[image: refer the below screen shot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing

```
dataType: 'script'
```

to accept html

```
dataType: 'html'
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :)