# having a second drop down list with ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My current state is:

view:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@supervisor) do |f| %>
              <%= f.error_messages %>
              <%= f.association :employee_department, as: :select %>
              <%= f.input :employee_position_id , collection: @departments, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :employee_positions, prompt: "Select Position" %>

              <%= f.input :employee_id , collection: @positions, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :employees%>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def new
    @supervisor = CounselorSupervisor.new
    @departments = EmployeeDepartment.order(:name)
    @positions = EmployeePosition.all
  end
```

counselor_supervisors.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('.counselor_supervisor_employee_id').hide()
  employee = $('#counselor_supervisor_employee_id').html()
  $('#counselor_supervisor_employee_position_id').change ->
    position = $('#counselor_supervisor_employee_position_id :selected').text()
    escaped_position = position.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
    options = $(employee).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_position}']").html()
    if options
      $('#counselor_supervisor_employee_id').html(options)
      $('.counselor_supervisor_employee_id').fadeIn()
    else
      $('#counselor_supervisor_employee_id').empty()
      $('.counselor_supervisor_employee_id').hide()
```

the coffee script code is from this screencast [Dynamic Select Menus (Revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised), but making the second drop list just show / hide is not a good solution for me , i need to send an ajax request to get the data of the second drop list and i will also add a beforeSend "is-loading.." , how can i add an ajax request in this case ? i have searched alot but i cannot achieve what i want, also i tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825793/how-to-change-select-box-values-based-on-the-other-drop-down-list-values-in-rail) but it did not work for me. my rails version is 3.2.14

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the followin approach (which I already used in some projects).

1. Attach an "on change" event listener in the first dropdown
2. When the event gets triggered, retrieve the right data (JSON in this case) with an AJAX call
3. On the callback of the AJAX call (re)populate the second dropdown with the data retrieved.

Coffescript:

```
    $('#counselor_supervisor_employee_position_id').change ->
      $.get('YOUR ROUTE HERE' + position_id + '/RESOURCES.json', (result) ->
      options = []
      $.each result, ->
        options.push($("<option />").val(this.RESOURCE_id).text(this.RESOURCE_NAME))
        event.field.find(SECOND_DROPDOWN_HERE).find('option').remove().end().append(options)
      )
```

Now you just need to respond to JSON in your action

Let me know if the answer is not clear, or if I'm forgetting some detail.